# Choppy audio with headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a MacBook Air with Yosemite, and no matter what I use- iTunes, Safari, chrome, etc, the audio comes out choppy like a cd when it skips, but this only happens when I'm listening through headphones, and I've tried multiple pairs. Is there anything I can do to fix this myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would submit that this is probably not something you will be able to fix yourself. It seems to me that your headphone jack is broken. Try blowing really hard into the jack in hopes you might dislodge some dirt or sand, but it most likely just faulty.